# How to execute mysql script with variables using PHP::PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I am unable to execut long script the pdo throws an  exception:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error
```

If I submit script which does not contain variables it runs w/o problem.
The same script runs on phpmyadmin interface.

Here is my code snippet:

```
 try {
 $dsn = "mysql:host=" . DB_SERVER . ";dbname=" . DB_DEFAULT;
 $db = new PDO($dsn, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
 $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
 $q = $db->query($query);
 if (!$q) {
 echo $db->errorInfo();
  } else {
        $rows = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    var_dump($e);
 }
```

Here is some test which does not execute by PDO:

```
SET @ra_LMC:=80.9;
SELECT @ra_LMC;
```

How I should execut with pdo the multi line scripts?

Thanks 
Arman.

Comment: Can we see what your query looks like?

Comment: The query fails if any "set" operator is exist.as written in example.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

PDO does not allow the execution of multiple statements in one query() request.
But your @ra_LMC variable should be visible in the current connection, so you can put your second line (SELECT) into a new query() call.

To read a whole script, you have to parse the file and run each statement with a call to query().

Answer (score 7):

PDO can only execute one statement at a time.  You can ether run the `SET` and `SELECT` as 2 separate statements.  Or you can set the variable using `FROM`.

```
SELECT @ra_LMC FROM (SELECT @ra_LMC:=80.9) q
```