# Mysql variables and multiple queries in PDO. UPDATE query doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I select data from `tab1` to a variable, and use it in another query, which updates `tab1`. Target column `target` is of type INT, so I round it before its set.

It works well in mysql workbench, also getting no error from php (error_reporting set to -1). It just doesn't really update the target column - it stays zero.

Any idea why?

```
$q = 'SELECT @tmp = ( SELECT t
                      FROM tab1
                      WHERE a_id = :id1 );
      UPDATE tab1
      SET target = ( SELECT ROUND( @tmp / ( SELECT COUNT(*)
                                            FROM tab2
                                            WHERE b_id = :id2 )));
      ';

$sth = $dbh->prepare( $q );
$sth->execute( array( ':id1' => $id, ':id2' => $id ) );
```

Comment: [*You cannot use a named parameter marker of the same name twice in a prepared statement*](http://php.net/manual/pdo.prepare.php). Also, to support multi-queries, you need to make sure the `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` attribute is set to `true`

Comment: `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` is set to `1`. Also, just tried to rename named params, and still no success. Thanks a lot for your time though!

Comment: Please reflect any code changes in your question above. Also, what error mode is your PDO connection using?

Comment: code edited. Using `PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING`

Comment: I'd go with *exception* mode, just in case any warnings are being swallowed somehow

Comment: By default user variables in MySql are disabled. You have to allow them in your connection. I'll see if I can find how in google.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683110/how-to-execute-mysql-script-with-variables-using-phppdo

Comment: @Phil I switched to `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`, but don't get anything at all.
@MathewFoscarini I believe PDO of php 5.3+ should allow you to use multiple queries by default

Comment: @MathewFoscarini I think you can do multi-queries with PDO_MYSQLND and `ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` set to `true`.

Comment: User variables for MySQL.NET connector are disabled by default, but I can not confirm this is true for PDO/PHP. You'd have to run a simple `SET @t = 1; SELECT @t;` test.

Comment: @Phil `You cannot use a named parameter marker of the same name more than once in a prepared statement, unless emulation mode is on.` your first comment is almost true.

Answer (score 0):

When using `SELECT` with user variables, we must use a different assignation, which is `:`. be sure to have emulate prepares set to true.

```
$q = 'SELECT @tmp:= ( SELECT t
                  FROM tab1
                  WHERE a_id = :id1 );
      UPDATE tab1
      SET target = ( SELECT ROUND( @tmp / ( SELECT COUNT(*)
                                        FROM tab2
                                        WHERE b_id = :id2 )));
     ';
$sth = DB::query( $q );
var_dump($sth->fetch());
$sth->nextRowset();
var_dump($sth);
```

but mysql reference http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html states that we should set user-defined variables with `SET`

so in your case:

```
$q = 'SET @tmp = ( SELECT t
                      FROM tab1
                      WHERE a_id = :id1 );
      UPDATE tab1
      SET target = ( SELECT ROUND( @tmp / ( SELECT COUNT(*)
                                            FROM tab2
                                            WHERE b_id = :id2 )));
      ';
```