# Update order column from a list of IDS

Tags: mysql

I have a list of N ids (for example: 803, 518, 361) on a MySQL Server 5.7.24

Current values are

```
+-----+-------+
| id  | order |
+-----+-------+
| 361 |     1 |
| 518 |     2 |
| 803 |     3 |
+-----+-------+
```

I want to update `order` column from a list of ids, getting order from id position.

This query returns the correct `rownum` for each `id`:

```sql
SELECT `id`, (@rownumber := @rownumber + 1) `rownum`
FROM `comments`
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rownumber := 0) `cross`
WHERE `id` IN (803, 518, 361)
ORDER BY FIELD (`id`, 803, 518, 361) ASC;

+-----+--------+
| id  | rownum |
+-----+--------+
| 803 |      1 |
| 518 |      2 |
| 361 |      3 |
+-----+--------+
```

But on update, this positions are not set:

```
UPDATE `comments` `target`
JOIN (
    SELECT `id`, (@rownumber := @rownumber + 1) `rownum`
    FROM `comments`
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rownumber := 0) `cross`
    WHERE `id` IN (803, 518, 361)
    ORDER BY FIELD (`id`, 803, 518, 361) ASC
) `source` ON `target`.`id` = `source`.`id`
SET `target`.`order` = `source`.`rownum`;

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 3  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
```

The order value was not updated:

```
SELECT `id`, `order` FROM `comments`
WHERE `id` IN (361, 518, 803)
ORDER BY `order` ASC;

+-----+-------+
| id  | order |
+-----+-------+
| 361 |     1 |
| 518 |     2 |
| 803 |     3 |
+-----+-------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Where is the problem on the queries?

Thanks!

**UPDATE 1:**

Also, not working

```
UPDATE `comments` `target`, (
    SELECT `id`, (@rownumber := @rownumber + 1) `rownum`
    FROM `comments`
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rownumber := 0) `cross`
    WHERE `id` IN (803, 518, 361)
    ORDER BY FIELD (`id`, 803, 518, 361) ASC
) `source`
SET `target`.`order` = `source`.`rownum`
WHERE `target`.`id` = `source`.`id`;
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error and it works for me.

Comment: @P.Salmon oh, it's strange... I have a script with fixed ids on SQL to execute in a row to test, and is not working.

Comment: `FIELD (id, 803, 518, 361)` in the first query vs `FIELD (803, 518, 361)` in the second one -- is that an error in the copy you posted or also different in the code you actually use?

Comment: @sticky bit well spotted,

Comment: @stickybit was an copy&paste error. In my code I'm using `FIELD (id, 803, 518, 361)`.

Comment: Is `id` the primary key or at least unique?

Comment: @stickybit yes, only `id` is the primary key on this table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `id` is the primary key, you could simply do:

```
UPDATE `comments`
       SET `order` = field(`id`,
                           803,
                           518,
                           316)
       WHERE `id` IN (803,
                      518,
                      361);
```

`field()` already produces the `1`, `2` or `3`.

Answer (score 1):

The following query should do the trick :

```
SET @rownumber = 0;
UPDATE comments
SET `order` = @rownumber:= @rownumber + 1
WHERE id IN (803, 518, 361)
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

See [this db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4vqcbphHX79oTh7pgB9BnM/1)

Comment: I can't do it because is from a PHP script and I only can execute one query at once. Multiples queries are not allowed.

Comment: [mysqli::multi_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) is your friend @Lito

Comment: I'm using PDO ;)

Comment: @Lito : ok then you can simply run the two statements, one after the other

Comment: Example here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24958367/php-pdo-using-mysql-variables

Answer (score 0):

As I'm working with queries on PHP, thanks to @GMB with idea about run two different statements:

```php
$db->exec('SET @rownumber = 0;');

$db->exec('
    UPDATE `comments`
    SET `order` = @rownumber := @rownumber + 1
    WHERE `id` IN (803, 518, 361)
    ORDER BY FIELD (`id`, 803, 518, 361) ASC;
');
```